# Is there a way to make s tkinter widget lose focus?

Tags: python, tkinter

That is, without doing focus_set on some other widget?

The original post ended with the sentence above, but **it did not meet quality standards**. These standards demand that the problem is described completely, including what one has tried. They insist on proper grammar too.

Well, it is not really a problem, just a question. I tried to find a widget method, say, focus_unset, that would do the trick. I didn't. My grammar is proper. Maybe the robotic police is confused with terms like focus_set?

Answer (score 0):

No. Some widget must have focus. You can set focus to the root window if you don't have any other widgets that naturally accept keyboard input.